# How to configure SpringSecurityDialect in spring boot to get sec:authorize working

Tags: spring-boot, security, configuration, thymeleaf

`sec:authorize` seems not to work!

Neither `Log Out` nor `Login` is showing when I launch the application despite tweaking here and there...

The following code is not showing anything in my html file:

```
               <li class="nav-item"
                    sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
                    <form th:action="@{/logout}"
                          method="post"
                          name="logoutForm">
                    </form>
                    <a class="nav-link"
                       href="#"
                       onclick="document.logoutForm.submit()">
                        <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>Log Out</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"
                    sec:authorize="isAnonymous()">
                    <form th:action="@{/login}"
                          method="post"
                          name="loginForm">
                    </form>
                    <a class="nav-link"
                       href="#"
                       onclick="document.loginForm.submit()">
                        <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>Log In</a>
                </li>
```

Below is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'org.launchcode'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '14'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

    dependencies {

        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:2.2.7.RELEASE'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
        implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto'
        implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:2.2.6.RELEASE'
        implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:5.1.4.RELEASE'
        implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:5.3.2.RELEASE'
        implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5:3.0.4.RELEASE'

        implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'

        implementation 'org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring5:3.0.11.RELEASE'
        implementation 'org.webjars:bootstrap:4.4.1-1'

        implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
        implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.0'

        developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
        testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
            exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
        }
    }

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Below is my configuration class containing the @Bean to register SpringSecurityDialect

```
@Configuration
public class WebApplicationConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    // Create spring-managed object to allow the app to access our filter
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() {
        return new AuthenticationFilter();
    }

    // Register the filter with the Spring container
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(authenticationFilter());
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringSecurityDialect springSecurityDialect() {
        return new SpringSecurityDialect();
    }

}
```

I think I followed the recommendations here https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity/tree/3.0-dev

But I do not know why it is still not working.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to say that I handled the problem differently (I could not figure out the setup of SpringSecurityDialect), So I did as follows:

```
<li th:if="${isLoggedIn != null}"
    class="nav-item">
    <form th:action="@{/logout}"
          method="post"
          name="logoutForm">
    </form>
    <a class="nav-link"
       href="#"
       onclick="document.logoutForm.submit()">
        <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>
        Log Out</a>
</li>
<li th:if="${isLoggedIn == null}"
    class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link"
       th:href="@{/login}">
        <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>
        Log In</a>
</li>
```

Which works fine. Perhaps in future I will try again learning how to use Spring Security dialect. Regards